# JOINS in MySql - which one?

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables in MySql (events and special_events) that do NOT have the same amount of columns (special_events has a unique datetime column - ruling out a UNION), however I want to merge the two tables together and return combined results generating the following shared columns: title, parent and directory...

```
SELECT title, parent, root 
FROM events 
WHERE root != "services" 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

What sort of JOIN do I need to use here.

NB. special_events also has title, parent, root columns etc.

Comment: Why is an extra column making `union` impossible? Just leave it from the select.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT title, parent, root 
  FROM events
  WHERE root != 'services'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT title, parent, root 
  FROM special_events
  WHERE root != 'services'
) s
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also fetch unique datetime column from special_events like,

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT title, parent, root, NULL as datetime_column
  FROM events
  WHERE root != 'services'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT title, parent, root, datetime_column
  FROM special_events
  WHERE root != 'services'
) s
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```